# datagridview throws `Object does not match target` type on anonymous list

Tags: datagridview, linq-to-entities, datasource, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

I get a result from a join and store it in an anonymous object:

```
var res = from route in context.Route join cust in context.Customers on route.customer_id equals cust.customer_id select new {sell_id = route.sell_id, company_name = cust.company_name};
List<Object> mylist = res.ToList();
```

Then I try to add another anonymous method (with the same 'properties') to the list

```
Object ab = new {sell_id=23, company_name="foo"};
mylist.Add(ab);
```

Even though when debugging in the watch window the list's items seem to live in harmony (they look identical!), but the gridview really doesn't like it:

```
datagridview.datasource = mylist;
```

I get the exception `'Object does not match target type'`

The above code is siplified for the example. I prefer not to create a special class for the join but to use the anonymous object.

Any workaround?

Comment: Are the datatypes of the anonymous class's properties the same? E.g. maybe `route.sell_id` is actually `Int16`, and you're manually adding (int)23.. Try looking at `mylist.Select(t=>t.GetType().ToString())` - are all the types the same?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - you might be on to something.. all the list values are "<>f__AnonymousType1`7[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]", while my added object's value is "<>f__AnonymousType0`7[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]". The problem is.. how do I convert or do something to the last object that it would be as the others, if I create it manually (not as a result of a query etc.)?

Comment: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) says "If two or more anonymous types in the same assembly have the same number and type of properties, in the same order, the compiler treats them as the same type." I take it you're doing this in a single assembly? Are you absolutely sure you are giving your extra object the same property names, with the same casing? `new { a = 1 }` and `new { A = 1 }` get different types, according to my testing.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Thank you! You are a genius! They weren't in the same assembly! Who would've thought.. I was fighting with this for hours